# Eloquent: Nested query to revert order in limited result

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

The following function (in my User Model) gives me the correct result for my chat system. Almost... I need to revert the order of the results.

```
public function getChatConv($cp, $page=1){
    $limit = $page * 20;
    $user = Authek::curUser();
    $res = Chatmessage::where('receipient',$cp)->where('sender',$user->id)
                    ->orWhere('receipient',$user->id)->where('sender',$cp)
                    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take($limit)->get();
    return $res;
}
```

It returns an object and I need an object as result. I tried already to convert the result to an array, revert the order and then convert the array back to object. This didn't work.

What I need is a nested query like the following raw SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
 SELECT * 
 FROM chatmessages
 WHERE (
  receipient =  '422'
  AND sender =  '22'
 )
 OR (
  receipient =  '22'
  AND sender =  '422'
 )
 ORDER BY created_at DESC 
 LIMIT 0 , 20
)faketable
ORDER BY created_at ASC
```

There are a few articles with nested queries, but I don't find a similar case and it would be good if someone could  do this in Eloquent without the use of Raw queries... It must be possible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

use take() and skip(),offset()

```
get 4 items from offset 3/4th:
Chatmessage::take(4)->offset(3)->get();
Or this (get 10 items from 8rd row):
Chatmessage::take(10)->skip(2)->get();

public function getChatConv($cp, $page=1){
    $limit = $page * 20;
    $user = Authek::curUser();
    $res = Chatmessage::where('receipient',$cp)->where('sender',$user->id)
                    ->orWhere('receipient',$user->id)->where('sender',$cp)
                    ->orderBy('created_at','desc')->take(3)->skip(2)->get();
    return $res;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me... I would have to calculate the Offset each time I run the query, meaning that I need to get all results first:
`$offset = count($allresults) - ($page * 20)`
I don't want that.